# JSF-Primefaces pickList update on every click of the tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to achieve following use-case -

```
<p:tabView id="top-level-tab">
            <p:tab title="TabA" id="tab-A">
                <ui:include src="tabA.xhtml" />             
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="TabB" id="tab-B">
                <ui:include  src="tabB.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

form in tab-A submits some values and persists in DB. When the tab-B gets clicked, the recently persisted value should be displayed in the PickList of tab-B. JSF constructs the view tree and gets cached at the server-side, this leads to no update on the PickList of tab-B.
Seeking help from experienced JSF-Primefaces developers, as I am very new to JSF-Primefaces.

tabB.xhtml

```
<h:form id="tabBForm">

<p:pickList id="tabBPickList" value="#{tabBController.countries}"  var="countries" itemLabel="#{countries}" itemValue="#{countries}" required="true"/>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="tabBForm"/>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Why don't you explicitly update the specific components in the other tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cache attribute of the tabView to false.

```
<p:tabView id="top-level-tab" cache="false">
```

Quote from primefaces documentation:

> When tab contents are lazy loaded by ajax toggleMode, caching only
>   retrieves the tab contents once and subsequent toggles of a cached tab
>   does not communicate with server. If caching is turned off, tab
>   contents are reloaded from server each time tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by Kukeltje in the comments, adding `update="..."` attribute to `<p:commandButton ...>` in form A (the one that persists in the DB) should do the trick.

I checked it in the following code and it works:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:tabView id="tabView">
            <p:tab title="TabA" id="tab-A">
                <h:form id="tabAForm">
                    <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Enter country name" />
                    <p:inputText id="country" value="#{tabAController.countryName}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{tabAController.saveCountry}" update="tabView:tabBForm:tabBPickList" />
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="TabB" id="tab-B">
                <h:form id="tabBForm">
                    <p:pickList id="tabBPickList" value="#{tabBController.countries}"  var="countries" itemLabel="#{countries}" itemValue="#{countries}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" />
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean nr 1:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named (value = "tabAController")
@RequestScoped
public class TabAController {

    private String countryName;

    public String saveCountry() {
        CountryDAO dao = new CountryDAO();
        Country country = new Country();
        country.setCountryName(countryName);
        dao.saveCountry(country);
        return "";
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) { this.countryName = countryName; }
    public String getCountryName() { return countryName; }
}
```

Backing bean nr 2:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TabBController {

    private DualListModel<String> countries;

    public TabBController() {
        CountryDAO dao = new CountryDAO();
        List countriesObj = dao.getCountries();
        List<String> countriesSource = new ArrayList();
        for(Object country : countriesObj) {
            Country tmp = (Country) country;
            countriesSource.add(tmp.getCountryName());
        }
        List<String> countriesTarget = new ArrayList();
        countries = new DualListModel(countriesSource, countriesTarget);
    }

    public void setCountries(DualListModel<String> countries) { this.countries = countries; }
    public DualListModel<String> getCountries() { return countries; }
}
```